# Changing Field Types On Derived Classes

Tags: c#

Hey so I have a new model which is derived from another class which then has some attributes that are models and are derived from another class. I am needing to change the type from v1.models to v2.models. So for example my new model we will call it Model A with field something and another field that is a class.

```
public class A {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Item> { get; set; }
}
```

Then after that we have the Item class like so:

```
public class Item {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<People> People { get; set; }
}
```

the People class:

```
public class People : Person {
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the person class has the following field:

```
public Location Location {get; set; }
```

My problem is I need to update the Location to the V2 model for only the class A and none of the other classes that call it so I cannot change it down the pipeline. So currently it is A.People.LocationV1 and I am needing it to be A.People.LocationV2 instead. Would creating a new flow for things with new separate classes  be the best option? There are more fields in these classes I just omitted the unnecessary ones.

Comment: What relevance do `A` and `Item` have to your question?

Comment: As a side issue, `People : Person` sounds like a recipe for disaster. People are _not_ a person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will still need to change a lot of the code if that's what you want to avoid.
Since there will be 2 `Person` with 2 kinds of Location types, I think either you need to use a generic class or create a new `PersonV2` class with a different `LocationV2`. Usually, the latter is the approach that you might want to use since it represents a different kind of data type.

Just in case you want to use generic, I think this is what it should look like. Or, you can change class `A` to a generic class as well. Note, you will still need to change the other class using `Item`, `People`, `Person` to also give the `Location` class type.

```
public class A {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Item<LocationV2>> { get; set; }
}

public class Item<T> {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<People<T>> People { get; set; }
}

public class People<T> : Person<T> {
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Person<T> {
    public T Location { get; set; }
}
```